# Android Studio Gradle Icon Grey-Bullish

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I tried to find an answer regarding the android studio gradle bar, but failed to do so. In my project, my gradle has a grey-bullish icon instead of the green-round one that most people seem to have. What is the difference between those and how does it affect my project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it could be an elephant... you're probably fine. 

Comment: Now that you mention it, it is an elephant! jaja. But does this affect the code? or is it just like a "new icon"? Thanks man!

Comment: It's just a new icon.